# What happens if my DispatchGroup never finishes

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have many asynchronous tasks that need to all be completed before I can move on, so I'm using a DispatchGroup. However, I am able to tell if one of the tasks fails early, and I would usually call a completion handler.

If I leave the scope of the function by calling a completion handler, what happens to the DispatchGroup?

Is the memory allocated forever? Is it possible that if leave is called enough times eventually (maybe due to a bug) that the notify block can still be called?

Example:

```
func example(completion: @escaping (Bool) - Void) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()
    asyncFunction1 {
        if result == false {
            completion(false)
        } else {
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.enter()
    asyncFunction2 { result in
        if result == true {
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

In the example above I have two asynchronous functions. The first function might call `completion(false)`, and the second function only calls `leave` on success. While it might not be the best example of code, these conditions are possible. What happens to the notify block?

Comment: I'd suggest to add a simple code example to describe the case.

Comment: You can call these functions nested. Or you can return bool in async function and call the dispatchGroup.leave() in false state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the swift's source on GCD:
https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/master/src/semaphore.c

It seems the block will be allocated and never released. Meaning, the memory the block retains will also never be released.

Comment: Love how people answer "Don't do it" to a "what if" question. If you don't know the answer, just don't answer instead of arguing "why do you want to know?" I totally agree with what you said. If we never made mistakes, why do we need debugging tools in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The dispatchgroup must be notified whenever a code block enters the group as well as whenever a codeblock leaves the group.

That means, `dispatchGroup.leave()` must be called regardless of success or failure of your function.

When all blocks are finished, the dispatchgroup gets notified.

Comment: I'm wondering what happens when leave is never called. Just because it must be called, doesn't mean it always will be called.

Comment: The design contract for dispatch groups state that it must be called. Therefore, failing to call it is a violation of the design contract and has undefined results. Even if you examine one implementation at one point in time, there's no guarantee that the behavior won't change over time. The only correct answer to your question is "your program is broken in some unspecified way".

Answer (score -1):

> I'm wondering what happens when leave is never called. Just because it must be called, doesn't mean it always will be called.

Well, *don't* "never call" it. You *must* arrange your code so that `leave` is called by every possible exit path. If you can't, don't use dispatch groups.

If necessary, you can pass the dispatch group itself into the completion handler so that it can call `leave` for you. But one way or another, call `leave`.

Comment: Answering a question as "Don't" is not a valid answer. Stackoverflow is for answering questions asked, not the question you wish was asked.